# how to use the split in Python

Tags: python, excel

```
import xlrd
import urllib.request

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx');
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0);
num_rows = sheet.nrows -1;
print(num_rows);
print('\n');
inputI=str(300);
inputP=str(15);
inputF='d';
content=sheet.cell_value(0,0);
address='http://www.google.com/finance/getprices? q='+content+'&i='+inputI+'&p='+inputP+'d&f='+inputF;
response = urllib.request.urlopen(address);
data = response.readlines().split('\n');
print(data);
```

When I run it, it will always show that 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. what should I do to fix it? Really appreciate it.

Comment: I know that here I need to get a string to use the split, but I could not find the correct way to get the string from the excel.

Comment: Not knowing how to work with basic types in a language is a big problem. I suggest you spend some time reading and playing with some examples in the docs before you proceed further.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e.g. Remove your `urllib`stuff etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method readlines() reads until EOF using readline() and returns a list containing the lines.

You can do something like:

```
data = response.readlines()
for line in data:
    # I guess you will get byte here, so you have to convert them to utf-8
    print(line.decode("utf-8", errors='ignore').split("\n")[0])
```

And also you can use readline() to do this.

Comment: Is there anyway that I could store every line? Should I make a list here to store? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Response.readlines() provides a list of lines. So it means that you are trying to split the list, which is not possible.

Instead try to take each line and then perform any processing you want to.